# Playing AVI movie on directx 9 surface

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directx-9, directshow.net

I have got a directx9 window and i want to play an avi-video on a texture.
i have heard that i can use directshow to do this?

if this is really posssible, where can i find tutorials or sample code to do this?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[DirectShow Samples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Texture3D9 Sample Playback    Draws video on a Microsoft DirectX 9.0 texture surface.

You will need to look for an older Windows SDK or DirectX SDK to find this sample though. I think it is removed from latest Windows SDK already.

`\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\Players\Texture3D9`

Comment: thanks! actually it seems to be pretty hard to find an old DirectX SDK where this sample is included

Comment: hm, i didnot find this sample neither in an old directx SDK nor in an actual windows SDK

Comment: Look into older SDK, or email me